# Detailed storyboard with 3 issued with

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, detailview

as implemented in the Xcode of a detailed storyboard with 3 issued with Tableview depending on id.
Row in table hav Name and Id(int value)

```
If id= 1  i need load OneViewController
If id= 2 i need load TwoViewController
If id= 3 i need load ThreeViewController
```

I use Navigation controller from Storyboard

Comment: Great, but where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add viewControllers to storyboard give them storyboardId same as that of their name.

[image]

Create a dataSourceArray which will hold dictionary objects with Id and Name values

```
#define kItemId @"Id"
#define kItemTitle @"Name"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSourceArray = @[@{kItemId: @1,kItemTitle:@"First"},
                             @{kItemId: @2,kItemTitle:@"Second"},
                             @{kItemId: @3,kItemTitle:@"Third"}];

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.dataSourceArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row][kItemTitle];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row];

    NSUInteger tag = [dict[kItemId]integerValue];

    NSString *identifier = nil;

    switch (tag) {
        case 1:
        {
            identifier = @"OneViewController";
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            identifier = @"TwoViewController";
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            identifier = @"ThreeViewController";
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    viewController.title = identifier;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController
                                         animated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestTableNavigation.zip)

Comment: Thank you very helped.
Now but a new problem appeared without seque As given variable in detail view.

Comment: @PetroNepyivoda Sorry, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I want transmit wariable from ViewController to DetailView

Comment: Like Seque OneViewController *detail = [???????????]; detail.Name = self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row][kItemTitle]; - for example In OneViewController   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Name;

Comment: @PetroNepyivoda Now I got it you can move the instantiation of a viewController inside the switch statement. Can you mention what are the specific data that you want to assign?

Comment: I have NSString variable in all 3 DetailViewControllers and i need  Beam String from TableView to DetailView

Comment: I try. It works. You really help me, thanks!!! I accept your ansver.